# Printing Issue with deleted content

Tags: excel, vba

So we created some code that will allow a user to enter multiple pages of data and then just click a print button to print the number of pages of data they have entered. However we are running into a problem where by if a user enters 300 rows of data, then deletes the last 100 lines, it is still printing 300 rows of data, rather than 200.

Any suggestions?

Code:

```
Sub LastRowInOneColumn()            
    If Range("C19") = "Enter any special posting instruction here." Then
        Range("C19:I26").ClearContents
    End If

    Dim MySheet As Worksheet
    Set MySheet = Worksheets("SIF Sheet")

    With MySheet
        Dim xFirstEmptyRow As Long
        xFirstEmptyRow = .Cells(30, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
        Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut
    End With    
End Sub
```

[image: Sample Picture]
Imagine instead of 30-32, rows of 30-300 filled out with sample data. Then rows 300 back to 200 deleted on purpose(say it wasnt needed). Its still printing up to row 300, instead of to row 200.

**Update**
I tried playing around with some other variations and came up with this but its throwing an error saying cannot use that command on overlapping selections:

```
Sub LastRowInOneColumn()            
    If Range("C19") = "Enter any special posting instruction here." Then
        Range("C19:I26").ClearContents
    End If

    Dim MySheet As Worksheet
    Set MySheet = Worksheets("SIF Sheet")

    Rows("30:1058").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete

    With MySheet    
        Dim xFirstEmptyRow As Long
        xFirstEmptyRow = .Cells(30, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
        Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut
    End With    
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no rest of the code. The code was designed to read down the sheet one line at a time, stopping at the point there is no more data and then print at that point. Sorry pasted in wrong code section.

Comment: Please post some sample data. the code is just printing the whole page.

Comment: Clearing content does not delete rows.

Comment: So i would have to manually highlight the rows, right click delete rows in order to not have them print?

Comment: could I add something like:


`On Error Resume Next
Columns("A,B,C,D,E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: @Gehn47 never use `On Error Resum Next` without a complete error handling! This line will hide **all** error messages but not only the next one. You might benefit from reading [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling) • You might also benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others are saying, clearing does not delete the records, but even if you delete the rows, excell sometimes keeps the Printing area in memory.

So I would suggest to change the Printing area by macro 
you can look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.printarea